# What is the strength of having all sets being elements of supertransitive models of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

What is the consistency strength of the following prinicple?

Every set is a member of a [supertransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertransitive_class) model of $\sf ZFC$.

Formally this means adding the following sentence to axioms of $\sf ZFC$:

$\forall x \exists M :( M \models {\sf ZFC}) \land \operatorname {supertransitive}(M) \land x \in M$

Is it equivalent to having a proper class of worldly cardinals?

Comment: Can you remind me what is a supertransitive set?

Comment: @YairHayut, a transitive set where every subset of an element of it is an element of it.

Comment: I think your axiom is missing "$x\in M$".

Comment: Isn't a supertransitive model of ZFC necessarily $V_\kappa$ for some inaccessible $\kappa$?

Comment: @JamesHanson, No. $\kappa$ can be singular, a worldly cardinal. See: https://mathoverflow.net/a/398527/95347

Comment: @Wojowu, Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/398526/7206 is essentially answering the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every level of the cumulative hierarchy is supertransitive, so "There is a proper class of worldly cardinals" clearly implies the principle in question.

Conversely, if $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ is supertransitive then $M$ computes powersets correctly: if $x\in M$ then $\mathcal{P}(x)\subseteq M$ so $\mathcal{P}(x)^M=\mathcal{P}(x)$. Consequently, every supertransitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is some $V_\alpha$.

So the answer to your question is **yes**, by virtue of the fact that the supertransitive models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ are essentially-by-definition the worldly levels of the cumulative hierarchy.